# Upperbound for the definite integral $f(t)=\int_{2}^{t}\frac{\sin^{2}(\pi \frac{\Gamma ^{2}(x)}{x})}{\sin^{2}(\frac{\pi }{x})}dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

What is a good upper bound for this function?
$$f(t)=\int_{2}^{t}\frac{\sin^{2}(\pi \frac{\Gamma ^{2}(x)}{x})}{\sin^{2}(\frac{\pi }{x})}dx$$

I managed to find this.

$$f(t)=\int_{2}^{t}\frac{\beta ^{2}(\frac{\Gamma ^{2}(x)}{x},1-\frac{\Gamma ^{2}(x)}{x})}{\beta ^{2}(\frac{1}{x},1-\frac{1}{x})}dx$$

But i don't know what to do next.

Comment: Its pretty unlikely.

Comment: Well i was working on the prime counting function and then this came up.

Comment: I'm not going to hold my breath on this one.

Comment: I think this is MUTO.